# Area under the curve?

Tags: calculus

The given function is $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$
When we draw any arbitrary tangent to the curve we get the same area,why?
Can anyone explain?

Comment: The area of what? The triangle formed by tangent line and x,y-axes?

Comment: Can you find the the equation of the tangent line at $(c,1/c)$? The area of the region under a tangent of the right branch, above the $x$-axis, and in the first quadrant,  is half the product of the $x$ and $y$-intercepts of the tangent line.

Comment: Did you mean the area of triangles enclosed by the axis and the tangent to $\dfrac1x$ is always constant, no matter what value of $x$ you pick?

Comment: and the area is always $2$ unit square.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey how is it 2 always, plz elaborate

Comment: @Tunk-Fey yes!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y-y_0=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$
$$y-\frac{1}{x_0}=-\frac{1}{x_0^2}(x-x_0)$$
$$y=-\frac{1}{x_0^2}x+\frac{2}{x_0}$$

So the intersection with the axis are in 
$$y=\frac{2}{x_0},x=0$$
$$x=2x_0,y=0$$

Then the area is:
$$A=\frac{1}{2}\frac{2}{x_0}2x_0=2$$

Or:

$$A=\int_0^{2x_0}\left(-\frac{1}{x_0^2}x+\frac{2}{x_0}\right)dx=-\frac{4}{2}\frac{x_0^2}{x_0^2}+\frac{2}{x_0}2x_0=2$$

Comment: The area should be $2$.

Comment: Double check the intersection with the $x$-axis. The area should be $2$.

Comment: @DavidH fixed thanks for the correction

Comment: FYI, I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey not problem, anyway the solution now is fine

Comment: @rlartiga I tried to remove my downvote after your correction but apparently it's locked in now. :( I upvoted one of your other responses to balance things out.

Comment: @DavidH no problem